# ionic cordova plugin add cordova-pdf-generator error al instalar

Tags: android, angular, ionic, ios, cordova

Estoy instalando ionic cordova plugin add cordova-pdf-generator pero me manda este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda porfavor

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/cesarvr/pdf-generator.git --nofetch
```

Comment: Gracias si lo instalo

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió no olvides marcarla como aceptada para que pueda ser encontrada por otros con el mismo problema.